# Chatbot - Botman functions not working

Tags: php, facebook, chatbot

I am using Botman 2.0 to build a Facebook Messenger chatbot.

Everything is fine with webhook verification and the `hear()` and `reply()` methods work well.

But, it looks like other methods don't work.

*i.e.*

Whenever I use the `say()` method, it never works. My server receives the request from Messenger, but it does not respond with the message response.

I have test with Botman's main example:

```
$botman->hears('Hello BotMan!', function($bot) {
    $bot->reply('Hello!');
    $bot->ask('Whats your name?', function($answer, $bot) {
        $bot->say('Welcome '.$answer->getText()); //this never works
    });
});
```

Additionally, when I try to use `ButtonTemplate` it raises an exception:

`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ButtonTemplate' not found`

Even though Botman's Facebook Driver is loaded:

`DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\FacebookDriver::class);`

And my `composer.json` file looks right:

```
"require": {
        "botman/driver-facebook": "^1.7"
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi,

I am getting this issue can you please help me?

Fatal error: Class 'BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager' not found

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I have same bug and I had try follow the guides, But it still does not work, Do you have some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need add in your header the following classes:

```
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Commands\AddStartButtonPayload;
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Commands\AddGreetingText;

use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Extensions\ButtonTemplate;
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Extensions\ElementButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I added the below Facebook extensions immediately after the controller class

```
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Extensions\Element as Element; 
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Extensions\ElementButton as ElementButton; 
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Extensions\ButtonTemplate as ButtonTemplate; 
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Extensions\GenericTemplate as GenericTemplate; 
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\Extensions\ListTemplate as ListTemplate;

$botman = resolve('botman');

$botman->hears('Hello BotMan!', function($bot) {
    $bot->reply('Hello!');
    $bot->ask('Whats your name?', function($answer, $bot) {
        $bot->say('Welcome '.$answer->getText()); //this works
    });
});
```

You can check from this link as well https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/botman/botman/1055/522233149